# horizontal layout - sticky footer hides horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, layout, horizontal-scrolling, sticky-footer

I have this code for horizontal layout in a div but when I add footer, which should stick to bottom, the horizontal scrollbar disappears.

also the container and footers height & width should be complementary to the browser window.

here is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Project</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrap">

        <div class="container">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        </div><!-- end CONTAINER -->

        </div><!-- end WRAP -->

        <div id="footer">
        <ul id="nav">
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4</li>
        <li>Menu 5</li>
        <li>Menu 6</li>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- end FOOTER -->

        <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.6.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(function(){
                var width = 0;
                $('#wrap .container div').each(function() {
                width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
            });
            $('#wrap .container').css('width', width + "px");
        });
        });//]]>  
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
html, body {
height: 100%;}

body:before,#wrap:before{content:'';float:left;height:100%;margin-top:-999em;} 

#wrap{
min-height: 100%;
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;
background-color: red;}

#wrap:after {
content:'';
height:200px;
display:block;
clear:both;}

#wrap .container{  }
#wrap .container div{
border:1px solid #CCC;
float:left;
width:200px;
height:200px;}

#footer{
margin:-200px auto 0;
height:200px;
width:100%;
background-color: blue;}

ul#nav{list-style-type: none;margin:0;padding: 0}
ul#nav li{display: inline;}
```

here is d fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/MsF59/1/

sticky footer was taken from 
http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/css/css3-sticky-footer.php (METHOD 2)

i suppose d negative margin in footer makes it disappear, but without it the footer wont stick to d bottom.

where is d issue basically?

Comment: no scrollbar in the fiddle :(

Comment: exactly dat is d prob.styling footer to stay a d bottom will disable d hori scrollbar. bt click on d red element and navigate using arrow keys, it will scroll. y is d scrollbar hiding???